# To print a message if number of rows left are zero

Tags: android

When I click `btn2`, a row/children is deleted as expected. However, when there are no more children left, the application crashes despite the check for non-zero value of `getChildCount()`. Why does this happen?

```
  btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int j= t1.getChildCount();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
              if(j==0) // doesn't work
              {
                    Toast.makeText(
                          create_form.this,
                          "Can not delete more rows",
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show();
              }
              else 
              {
                    TableRow lastRow = (TableRow) t1.getChildAt(t1.getChildCount() - 1);
                    TableRow secondlastRow = (TableRow) t1.getChildAt(t1.getChildCount() - 2);
                    t1.removeView(lastRow);
                    t1.removeView(secondlastRow);
              }
        }
  });
```

Comment: If you move `int j= t1.getChildCount();` into the `onClick` method does it work?

Comment: just use `t1.getChildCount()` as condition, `if(t1.getChildCount()==0)`

Comment: @SlashmanX..No then it wont work

Comment: @Yazan  It is not working either

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not update `j` after you remove the rows.
2. You are removing two rows but checking if there is at least one row. If the number of rows is odd, it will try to remove two rows when only one is left. You should check for that as well.

Comment: btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        { int j= t1.getChildCount();               public void onClick (View v) {
                    if (j == 0) 
                    {
                        //CODE
                    } else {
                        TableRow lastRow = (TableRow) t1.getChildAt(t1.getChildCount() - 1);
                        TableRow secondlastRow = (TableRow) t1.getChildAt(t1.getChildCount() - 2);
                        t1.removeView(lastRow);
                        t1.removeView(secondlastRow);
                        j=j-2;
                    }}});

Comment: Edited like above code.But still not working.App is crashing everytime i click the button when rows are 0

Comment: It's not crashing here then or you are changing the rows somewhere else as well

Answer (score 0):

Place `int j= t1.getChildCount();` inside the `onClick` method. In your case, `j` is assigned only once when your anonymous class is being instantiated.

However, `onClick` method gets called whenever user clicks the button.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by changing the if condition

```
if (j <2)


 {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            create_form.this,
                            "Can not delete more rows",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show();
                }
```